# Neo4j's GraphAlgoFactory

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

Is there a way to represent the following query using GraphAlgoFactory for Java?

```
START n=some_node, m=some_other_node
MATCH p = n-[*..10]->m
WHERE ALL (x in nodes(p) WHERE (x.title? =~ "regex")) 
RETURN p;
```

I know it implements some useful graph algorithms, but I wanted more specific results.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In traversing your may follow parameters: finding path - "from `n` to `m`", `depth` <= 10 (see  [find all shortest path](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-find-all-shortest-paths)).

You can also add filter by relationship type (but not by title of node):

`"relationships" : {
    "type" : "to",
    "direction" : "out"
  },`